# Moving from Python 3 to Python 2

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, compiler-errors

```
print('10 -> 2 [bd], 2 -> 10 [db]')
answ=input('select db or bd : ')

if  answ == "db":
a=input('enter a digit')
x=int(a)
list1 = []

while (x):
    x%2
    x//2

    if x==0:
        break
```

I began creating this on python 3.2, but then I had to move on python 2.7.5 and I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<file path>", line 3, in <module>
    answ=input('select db or bd : ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
>>>
```

I really don't know hat is all about, worked pretty fine on python 3.2 (sorry for my bad english).

Comment: replaced inputs with raw_inputs, and added spaces between equality signs, working. Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 2 the equivalent to `input` is called `raw_input`

so line 2 should be `answ=raw_input('select db or bd : ')`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input):

```
answ=raw_input('select db or bd : ')
```

[`input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) in Python 2.x evaluates input as real Python code.

Also, just a tip: these two lines:

```
x%2
x//2
```

don't do anything.  Perhaps you meant:

```
x %= 2
x //= 2
```

Comment: And for more information [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) has details.

Comment: @MarcelChyra - Hmm, that is very strange.  I ran the code in Python 2.7.5 and I didn't get the error at all.